# LWUIT Horizontal list scrolling gimping vertical form scrolling

Tags: java, java-me, scroll, lwuit

In LWUIT, I have a form that has around 4 horizontal lists. The lists' horizontal scrolling words perfectly.

However, when I want to scroll vertically up and down the form, it just ends up scrolling horizontally whichever list where the swipe begins, even though I'm swiping up and down and not left and right.

Is there any way to fix this?

Edit:
This is my layout for the form:

```
this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
this.setScrollableY(true);
```

Comment: The user comments that he doesn't need this info anymore...in the answrer's comments

Comment: @jmunoz This does not make the question itself invalid.

Comment: is this question really useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in LWUIT that wasn't designed for doing that, we fixed it in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com). Its not a trivial fix since we needed to refactor quite a lot of things.

Comment: That's quite unfortunate, as the project requirements are that it be done in LWUIT.. :/
Thank you for the clarification Shai. Now I know not to waste any more time trying to fix it..

Comment: Codename One is the unofficial successor of LWUIT so there is really no reason to use LWUIT. Since Chen and myself wrote LWUIT and are now writing Codename One I doubt the requirements make much sense.

Comment: The application I'm making will be integrated into a larger one by another company. And they use LWUIT. We tried convincing them to move to Codename one, but they refused..

Comment: Too bad, they should probably talk to us about that